# How to create custom controller in laravel nova

Tags: laravel-nova

I have some resource and all my resource direct to observer but i want manage request in controller.

I'm already tired of looking for a solution. How to i create custom controller for my resource?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the route want to change from route list using command `php atisan route:list` and then create new route from `web.php` or where ever you want to override it.